# Problem running two futures simultaneously

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-futurebuilder

I am calling two futures in my ui that need to be run simutaneously, I used two nested futurebuilders but that caused me null errors. I want to be able to run my futures at the same time , since they both have different return types I can't use future.await.
The second future calls on a Future function that takes my item's id from the first future as a parameter . This is the first future function , it returns a list of items:

```
myList = myQrqcListViewModel.articlesList;
    List<Qrqc>? qrqcList = myList;
    Future<List<Qrqc>>? _fetch(int count) {
      return Future.delayed(
        Duration(seconds: 1),
            () => qrqcList!.take(count).toList(),
      );

    }
```

The second one that takes the item's id from the first future :

```
futureQrqc = QrqcDetailViewModel().fetchQrqcDetail(qrqcList[index].id);
```

For now this is how am running both :

```
 return FutureBuilder(
                        future: futureQrqc,
                          builder: (BuildContext context,
                              // ignore: non_constant_identifier_names
                              AsyncSnapshot <QrqcDetails?> snapshot){


                            if (snapshot.hasData){

                              String? backgroundImage;

                              String? _setImage() {
                                String _mTitle = "${snapshot.data!.type}";


                                if(_mTitle == "Delivery") {
                                  backgroundImage = "assets/icons/delivery.png";
                                } else if(_mTitle == "Security") {
                                  backgroundImage = "assets/icons/security.png";
                                }
                                else if(_mTitle == "Quality") {
                                  backgroundImage = "assets/icons/quality.png";
                                }
                                else if(_mTitle == "Cost") {
                                  backgroundImage = "assets/icons/Cost.png";
                                }
                                else if(_mTitle == "People") {
                                  backgroundImage = "assets/icons/people.png";
                                }
                                print("_mTitle: $_mTitle");
                                print("_mTitle: $backgroundImage");
                                return backgroundImage; // here it returns your _backgroundImage value

                              }
                              Column(
                                children: [


                                  ConditionalBuilder(condition:qrqcList[index].status == 'INIT', builder: (context) => QrqcBody(
                                    child: QrqcCard(child:QrqcCardBody(
                                      color: Colors.orange,
                                      text: qrqcList[index].status,
                                      leading: QrqcCardLeaing(imgPath:_setImage()),
                                      trailing: QrqcCardtrailing(text:qrqcList[index].progress.toString(),percent: qrqcList[index].progress.toString(),),
                                      title: qrqcList[index].id.toString(),
                                      subtitle: qrqcList[index].title,
                                      chlidren: [
                                        QrqcDetailsCardFirstRow(
                                          product: snapshot.data?.product?? "No product" ,
                                          role: qrqcList[index].role?? "no role",
                                        ),
                                        const SizedBox(height: 10),
                                        QrqcDetailsCardSecondRow(
                                          perim: snapshot.data?.perimeter?? "no perim",
                                          date: convertDateTimeDisplay(snapshot.data!.creation_date??"no date"),
                                        ),
                                        const SizedBox(height: 10),
                                      ],
                                    )),
                                  ),
                                      fallback: null),
                                  ConditionalBuilder(condition:qrqcList[index].status == 'SUBMITTED', builder: (context) => QrqcBody(
                                    child: QrqcCard(child:QrqcCardBody(
                                      color: Colors.blueAccent,
                                      text: 'SUB',
                                      leading: QrqcCardLeaing(imgPath: "assets/icons/delivery.png"),
                                      trailing: QrqcCardtrailing(text:qrqcList[index].progress.toString(),percent: qrqcList[index].progress.toString(),),
                                      title: qrqcList[index].id.toString(),
                                      subtitle: qrqcList[index].title,
                                      chlidren: [
                                        QrqcDetailsCardFirstRow(
                                          product: 'product1',
                                          role:'role',
                                        ),
                                        const SizedBox(height: 10),
                                        QrqcDetailsCardSecondRow(
                                          perim: 'perim',
                                          date: '12/2/2021',
                                        ),
                                        const SizedBox(height: 10),
                                      ],
                                    )),
                                  ), fallback: null),
                                  ConditionalBuilder(condition:qrqcList[index].status == 'VALIDATED', builder: (context) => QrqcBody(
                                    child: QrqcCard(child:QrqcCardBody(
                                      color: Colors.green,
                                      text: 'Valid',
                                      leading: QrqcCardLeaing(imgPath: "assets/icons/delivery.png"),
                                      trailing: QrqcCardtrailing(text:qrqcList[index].progress.toString(),percent: qrqcList[index].progress.toString(),),
                                      title: qrqcList[index].id.toString(),
                                      subtitle: qrqcList[index].title,
                                      chlidren: [
                                        QrqcDetailsCardFirstRow(
                                          product: 'product1',
                                          role: 'role',
                                        ),
                                        const SizedBox(height: 10),
                                        QrqcDetailsCardSecondRow(
                                          perim: 'perim',
                                          date: '12/2/2021',
                                        ),
                                        const SizedBox(height: 10),
                                      ],
                                    )),
                                  ), fallback: null),
                                  ConditionalBuilder(condition:qrqcList[index].status == 'ESCALATED', builder: (context) => QrqcBody(
                                    child: QrqcCard(child:QrqcCardBody(
                                      color: Colors.red,
                                      text: 'ESCAL',
                                      leading: QrqcCardLeaing(imgPath: "assets/icons/delivery.png"),
                                      trailing: QrqcCardtrailing(text:qrqcList[index].progress.toString(),percent: qrqcList[index].progress.toString(),),
                                      title: qrqcList[index].id.toString(),
                                      subtitle: qrqcList[index].title,
                                      chlidren: [
                                        QrqcDetailsCardFirstRow(
                                          product: 'product1',
                                          role: 'role',
                                        ),
                                        const SizedBox(height: 10),
                                        QrqcDetailsCardSecondRow(
                                          perim: 'perim',
                                          date: '12/2/2021',
                                        ),
                                        const SizedBox(height: 10),
                                      ],
                                    )),
                                  ), fallback: null)
                                ],

                              );

                            }else if(snapshot.hasError){
                              return const NoDataUI();
                            }
                            return Text(snapshot.error.toString());


                          }




                      )
```

There's no Error in the stack trace it tells me the service fetched the data needed just fine

```
Instance of 'Qrqc', Instance of 'Qrqc', Instance of 'Qrqc', Instance of 'Qrqc', Instance of 'Qrqc', Instance of 'Qrqc', Instance of 'Qrqc', Instance of 'Qrqc', Instance of 'Qrqc', Instance of 'Qrqc', Instance of 'Qrqc', Instance of 'Qrqc', Instance of 'Qrqc', Instance of 'Qrqc', Instance of 'Qrqc', Instance of 'Qrqc', Instance of 'Qrqc', Instance of 'Qrqc', Instance of 'Qrqc', Instance of 'Qrqc', Instance of 'Qrqc', Instance of 'Qrqc', Instance of 'Qrqc', Instance of 'Qrqc', Instance of 'Qrqc', Instance of 'Qrqc', Instance of 'Qrqc', Instance of 'Qrqc', Instance of 'Qrqc', Instance of 'Qrqc', Instance of 'Qrqc', Instance of 'Qrqc', Instance of 'Qrqc']
flutter: fetched details
flutter: Instance of 'QrqcDetails'
```

But my ui tells me otherwise , this is what I get when I run the app :

[image]

I don't know what I should do to make both work , knowing that I need the first future to run in a future builder , how do I get the second future to work fine without a second future builder , and if it is possible to work with two nested future builders what seems to be wrong in my code, I tried several times.

Comment: How can you run two futures in parallel, when one needs the other's results?

Comment: write an `async` method that `await`s the first future and based on that result run the second future

Comment: @pskink  How to do so do you have an example please ? thank you so much

Comment: @nvoigt I mean in the same widget

Comment: see [Working with futures: async and await](https://dart.dev/codelabs/async-await#working-with-futures-async-and-await)